# Reading compressed (.xz) file in Apache pig

Tags: hadoop, compression, apache-pig, xz

I am trying to read .xz file compressed using [hadoop-xz](https://github.com/yongtang/hadoop-xz)  codec using pig script.

The sample code i tried is,

```
REGISTER hadoop-xz-1.4.jar
SET output.compression.enabled true;
SET output.compression.codec io.sensesecure.hadoop.xz.XZCodec;

msg = LOAD 'pigtest/newXZ.xz' USING PigStorage();
STORE msg INTO 'pigtest/output' USING PigStorage();
DUMP msg;
```

The result is still in a compressed format. Am i doing wrong or i have to use `XZInputStream` inside pig?

The running environment is HortonWorks Sandbox 2.2 (Hue)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do.

It seems like you want to read an XZ file so I would assume you need to setup the input codec not the output one.

I'm not a PIG user but from what I gather it cannot easily handle custom compression (unlike Hive and Streaming for example).